# Is dbase obsolete

Tags: dbase

Is dbase considered obsolete? There was a time when it was more prominent that SQL, but now it seems largely dying...

Comment: What century are you living in that you even need to ask this?  dBase hasn't been a valid choice since Windows 3.1.

Comment: I was going through some floppies and found dbase...then I checked their website and it says they support Windows 7...so I was curious. I was just curious to see if anyone still uses it...

Comment: SQL is *not* a database system.

Comment: I'm also curious to see if there are any web apps written in dbase.

Comment: dBASE (and other "XBase" dialects) is still GREAT for ad-hoc data fiddling and small data oriented scripts with simple UI's. I haven't found anything better for that niche. I get stuff done twice as fast as MS-Access. The language is compact, consistent, & intuitive. The imperative nature makes data more modular & inspect-able than SQL's functional style. I suppose it's all subjective, but I love that damned tool for quicky data scripting. There's a few annoyances, but every tool/language has warts; you just get used to them. God Save the dBASE Queen!  "Old" is not always "bad".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dBase as a DB system seems to have just about died out now.  The owning [company is still in business](http://www.databi.com/), so technically, it's not dead.

That being said, the dbase formatted files (dbf) are still used.  However, I think it's hard to justify using dBase for any new development, especially now that there are so many superior single file database solutions, such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

These provide far superior options, especially when doing operations across multiple tables.

Answer (score 3):

dBase is NOT OBSOLETE !!

Only if you do not want to work in DOS you can feel that it is obsolete.

We can even today write single and multiple table applications in our good old dBase
which can handle DMBS work for small and medium sized enterprises successfully.

The reports that are generated are pure text files which can be deployed on WEB.

Both FRONTEND and BACKEND along with DML and DDL at one place it is still a great
environment to work with.

Comment: Dbase _is_ obsolete, but that doesn't mean one can't use it anymore. Like others have suggested, things like SQLite are a much better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The Dbase format lives on in ESRI Shapefiles used for storing geospatial data. So DBF as a file format is still not dead...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dBase is obsolete.